# How to update Facebook status?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I wish to allow my WP application user to share text (put in this application) to update their facebook status.

I read it exists a project called [facebook c# sdk](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/phone/) but this page is empty!

Do you know if it exists a simple way to realise that?

Comment: There is no Windows Phone component yet, that's why the page is blank. They're working on it.

Comment: and other ways to realize that?

Comment: I believe you're using the word "realize" wrong - can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not english! ;)
I meant "make" instead of "realize".
So, are there others ways to make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the Share Status Task?

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

...

ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
shareStatusTask.Status = "Here's my new status!";
shareStatusTask.Show();
```